# Easylogging 8.91 not compling without c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, easylogging++

I want to use the library without C++11 but it won't compile for me:
(Theoretically it should as per documentation @http://easylogging.muflihun.com:
"For lower version of C++ (non-C++11), please consider using Easylogging++ v8.91. ")

error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

File structure:

./Main.cpp
./logger/easylogging++.h

Contents of Main.cpp:

```
#include "logger/easylogging++.h"
_INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
LINFO << "This is my first log";
return 0;
}
```

../src/logger/easylogging++.h: In function ‘std::string easyloggingpp::internal::threading::getCurrentThreadId()’:
../src/logger/easylogging++.h:691:16: error: ‘std::this_thread’ has not been declared
ss << std::this_thread::get_id();

Compiler: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1), OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Good answers: either defining a version which can be built with c++98, either defining the build environment for this version (8.91) for compilation.

Comment: Alternate solution which is also welcome: a good single-header logger library for c++98 which is easy to use (like DEBUG << "something";), can log to console and file below some loglevel and can log to only console above this loglevel (loglevel should be settable in runtime).

Comment: Looks like the logic in their header is "define `_ELPP_CXX11` any time it's GCC 4.8 or later". Just comment that out.

Answer (score 0):

As T.C. suggested in the solution is to change this section of code at the top of easylogging++.h:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#   define _ELPP_GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 \
                               + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 \
                               + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#   if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)
#      define _ELPP_CXX0X 1
#   elif (_ELPP_GCC_VERSION >= 40801)
#      define _ELPP_CXX11 1
#   endif // defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)
#endif // defined(__GNUC__)
```

Changing both `_ELPP_CXX0X` and `_ELPP_CXX11` to 0 will fix the issue.